# How to Use Visual Studio Resource Selector Dialog in Custom Designer

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, windows-forms-designer

Using .NET 4.0 with Visual Studio 2017 and Visual Basic .NET (could be done in C# just as well), I have created a WinForms application. As part of the application I have created a custom control by adding a new class and inheriting from System.Windows.Forms.Control

```
Public Class MyControl
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Control
End Class
```

If I add the custom control to a form, I can add a BackgroundImage using the Property Window. In the Property Window, if I click in the BackgroundImage property, it shows an ellipsis button. Clicking on that button will open a Select Resource Dialog window.

[image]

I have now created a custom designer for the control by inheriting from System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner . I have also created the designer form that pops up when the control is double clicked in design view. On the designer form I want to be able to choose a Background image using the same Select Resource dialog from Visual Studio that is shown above. I have been unable to find where the Select Resource Dialog exists.My suspicion was in the following assembly, but I did not find it.

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.dll
```

Can someone tell me the fully qualified namespace for the Select Resource Dialog used by Visual Studio and which assembly it exists in?

Comment: The dialog belongs to the `UiTypeEditor` of the property. You can show the property editor of all properties at design time using code. For more information read the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can show the property editor of all properties at design time using code. To do so, you can find the internal `EditorServiceContext` which is in `System.Design` assembly, and then invoke its `EditValue` method by passing the your control designer, the control to edit and the property name to edit.

**Example**

You can find the full source code for example here in this repository:

- [r-aghaei/ShowPropertyEditorSample](https://github.com/r-aghaei/ShowPropertyEditorSample)

The core part of the sample is the designer class:

```
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;
public class MyControlDesigner : ControlDesigner
{
    DesignerVerbCollection verbs;
    public override DesignerVerbCollection Verbs
    {
        get
        {
            if (verbs == null)
            {
                verbs = base.Verbs;
                verbs.Add(new DesignerVerb("Show Select Resource", 
                    (s, e) => ShowSelectResource()));
            }
            return verbs;
        }
    }
    public void ShowSelectResource()
    {
        var editorServiceContext = typeof(ControlDesigner).Assembly.GetTypes()
            .Where(x => x.Name == "EditorServiceContext").FirstOrDefault();
        var editValue = editorServiceContext.GetMethod("EditValue",
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static |
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public);
        editValue.Invoke(null, new object[] { this, this.Component, "SomeProperty" });
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe this is exactly what you need. Let me know if you have any question about the answer ...